# Create a sequence number for project task (Odoo 12)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to add sequence in tasks of project.But, this method showing sequence of couning for all tasks in different project.
how to start counting again for each time I create new project?

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('name_seq', _('New')) == _('New'):
            vals['name_seq'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].with_context(force_company=vals['company_id']).next_by_code(
                'task.project.sequence') or _('New')

        result = super(AddSequence, self).create(vals)
    return result
```

Any help please?

Comment: I think you want to use task numbering per project.

Comment: yes , if I have a project1 , tasks will be with sequence p-001 ; p-002 ; p-003 ;.... and for Project2 , tasks will be : P-001 ; P-002 ; P-003 ;..... I want that sequence start from 001 for each project.

Comment: For project number, you need to use `ìr.sequence` but for task number, you need to compute it in each project. For example you can achieve that  when you add a new task to a project .

Comment: You could add an integer field (number) to the project object, which is set to 0 or 1 by default. Then you hook into the create method of the task object and get the number of the (parent) project there, name the task as you like with the number and finally increase it.

Comment: How get value from the "project.project"  model to other model "project.task" in the create function . I get always  "False" value.

Answer (score 1):

I would try that, but no guarantee that it works since I have not tested it:

```
class ProjectProject(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.project'

    task_number = fields.Integer("Current Task Number", default=1)

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        result = super(ProjectTask, self).create(vals)
        number = self.project_id.task_number

        [... rest of your logic ...]

        self.project_id.task_number += 1
        return result
```